# Succinct way to listen to a single event

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Is there a succinct way to get only `child added` or whichever event? Right now I have to do the following, which looks stupid

```
ref.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
    override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {}
    override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {}
    override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {}
    override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
        subscriber.onNext(Value.parse(unitName, varName, p0))
    }
})
```

Comment: This is a great question. You shouldn't be forced to listen to all child events as it will incur additional costs to your bill for data downloaded. In iOS and Web Firebase SDK, you can listen to any specific child event, but in Android Firebase SDK you are forced to listen all child event. This seems like a bug in Android Firebase SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own abstract class that implements ChildEventListener, but doesn't provide an implementation of onChildAdded:

```
abstract class ChildAddedEventListener : ChildEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
    }

    override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
    }

    override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
    }

    override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {
    }
}
```

Then you subclass ChildAddedEventListener, and provide just the implementation you want:

```
class MyChildAddedEventListener: ChildAddedEventListener {
    override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

With this, you can use it as an inline object expression when adding it to the query:

```
query.addChildEventListener(object : ChildAddedEventListener() {
    override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
        subscriber.onNext(Value.parse(unitName, varName, p0))
    }
})
```

Comment: this is bad because you are still going to get charged for data downloaded for onChildChanged, onChildRemoved, and onChildMoved for $1 per 1GB. In iOS and Web, you can only listen to specific child event such as onChildAdded. Only in Android you are forced to listen to all child events. Could you please verify this limitation? Android Firebase SDK isn't working like iOS and Web Firebase SDK, and I have to create alternative (very inefficient way) to set up listeners specifically for Android

Comment: I want to listen only for onChildAdded and onChildRemoved, not onChildChanged. Now I have to put a flag somewhere when a child get pushed so that the client can reload the entire list upon child being added or removed. I cannot set up childEventListener, because if I set it up I will be charged for onChildChanged. I have a separate onChildChanged listener in subtrees. Android SDK ChildListener gives developers no flexibility and it is inconsistent to iOS and Web platforms.

Comment: @coolcool1994 If you have feedback or suggestions about the Firebase APIs, I suggest sending that to Firebase support.  Downvoting an answer won't change the reality of the way things work today.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I really appreciate you confirmation on this limitation. Thank you! I will just patch it on my end by putting in custom solution for just Android - just more work on my end. I can emulate childAdded and childDeleted by whenever I push or delete from a list, set a timestamp flag, and when that timestamp flag is less than current client local time stamp, refresh the whole list. Still there is nothing as great as Firebase!

Comment: I am submitting the support request as you said too. Thank you for everything you do.

Comment: turns out that both in iOS and Android you cannot just listen to one childEvent. You are forced to listen to all. And you have to pay for all the data downloaded for all child events. Be careful when you use this childListener in Real time database if you want to avoid a surprise bill.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the name of the pattern that ommits all methods are called Adapter, in your case:

```
ref.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventAdapter {
   override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
        subscriber.onNext(Value.parse(unitName, varName, p0))
    }
})
```

An (interface)adapter class is a class that implements the interface with empty methods, so you can choose which one you want to override

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
object EmptyChildEventListener : ChildEventListener {
     override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
     override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {}
     override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {}
     override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {}
     override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) { }
} 

ref.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener by EmptyChildEventListener {
     override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
         subscriber.onNext(Value.parse(unitName, varName, p0))
     }
})
```

---

**EDIT:** but you can supposedly improve upon this like so

```
inline fun DatabaseReference.onChildAdded(crossinline added: (DataSnapshot, String?) -> Unit) {
    this.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener by EmptyChildEventListener {
         override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) = added(p0, p1)
    })
})
```

Now you can do

```
ref.onChildAdded { p0, p1 -> 
    subscriber.onNext(Value.parse(unitName, varName, p0))
}
```

Comment: That's the best I can muster from my phone, I might be able to write you something with some crossinline

Comment: Check my revised answer from my PC